# uiwebview in uicollectionview getting white blank screen

Tags: swift, webview, uicollectionview

I had a problem with uiwebview and collectionview. loading local html files in webview.

```
webView.loadRequest(Request)
```

The problem is when scrolling multiple times forward and backward getting a white blank screen in uiwebview. Otherwise, it's working fine.
Using below code for loading cell.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
 {         
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: STR_CollectionCell_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as! HTMLCollectionViewCell

     let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])

     HTML_File_Name = Get_File_Name(Cellindex: indexPath.row)

     var FilePath = PATH_HTML_DE +  HTML_File_Name
     let url2 = URL(string: parameterString, relativeTo: textFileURL)!
     myRequest = URLRequest(url: url2)

     cell.LoadHTMLRequest(IN_Request: myRequest)

     return cell
}
```

Comment: CellForItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: STR_CollectionCell_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as! HTMLCollectionViewCell

Comment: Did you register the cell? Also edit the question with additional information. Don't add it to comments.

Comment: Please show respect to readers of your question, and take time to format code snippets in future. Also, variable and func names in Swift should be lowercase starting  `camelCase`, rather than uppercase starting `Snake_Case`. Using correct naming makes it easier for others to read.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I don't have any previous experience that's why? sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Better to have cache policy for loading web request again and again

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.something.com")
let url_request = URLRequest(url: url!,
                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad,
                  timeoutInterval: 10.0)

let webView = UIWebView()
webView.loadRequest(url_request)
```